# LangChain simple llm.predict in Angular returns empty result

Tags: angular, openai-api, langchain, angular-standalone-components

In my Angular 16 (standalone) app, I have a simple service to test LangChain against OpenAI.
This same code is working perfectly fine in a NodeJS app, however, **when run from Angular, the result returned from OpenAI is always an empty string:**

```
[llm/start] [1:llm:OpenAIChat] Entering LLM run with input: {
  "prompts": [
    "Israel's capital is"
  ]
}
console.js:132 [llm/end] [1:llm:OpenAIChat] [12ms] Exiting LLM run with output: {
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  ]
}
chat.service.ts:49 Completion returned in simplePromptTest:
```

Here is the Angular service code generating the above output:

```
import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";

const llm = new OpenAI({
  openAIApiKey: "sk-......ws",
  modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  temperature: 0,
  verbose: true
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

  constructor() { }

  async simplePromptTest() {
    const result = await llm.predict("Israel's capital is");
    console.log('Completion returned in simplePromptTest: ', result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Packages I installed are:

```
  npm install -S langchain
  npm install -S openai
```

What am I missing, please?

Comment: empty result means you made no call or there is error while making OpenAI call, you can break you program and see actually which steps is failing..

Comment: Thanks ZKS. Calls are registered in openai and charged. Same code runs OK in NodeJS, not Angular. console log shows no error. Where else shall I look for errors?

Comment: @MorSagmon I am having the same issue in my simple Angular app. Did you ever find a solution to this problem? If so I would be curious to know if a workaround exists. Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue. I reported it in LangChain repo. It seems to be related to how zones deal with async/await. The  error code shows promises being wrapped with Generator functions but these fail to wait and execute immediately before a response is produced.